# FBX export group instances to unity issue

Tags: export, unity

I have issues with exporting a group of meshes into unity.
I want to build a room in blender where the walls (img #1) are constructed separately and can be used as group instances in a new layer or scene (img #2).
All parts of a wall is parented under an empty. And so is the final room with the wall instances.

Problems occur when importing to unity, I select the walls (the group instances) in the room layer and tick "selected objects" and export.

Unity will import the three instances but with default position/rotation (img #3).

Also, when looking in the unity outliner, something seems off with the parent/child relations (img #4)

The goal is to export the room as is, like img #2.

Blender file: [image]

[image: img 1]
[image: img 2]
[image: img 3]
[image: img 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, I simply forgot the possibility of grouping the final wall pieces and create another group, this way I can just add a room instance to the scene and select that upon fbx export and unity will import this as one unit.

result: [image]

marking this as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing that empty object, in blender you use empty objects to avoid those z-axis issues between blender and unity. Also when exporting to FBX you could set what is your up-axis

EDITED:
From your shared file I exported one by one to FBX and them imported into Unity, without that axis issue, try that, BTW don't forget to set your forward and up axis... If it doesn't work let's go chat

[image]

Comment: Removing it produces the same result in unity, sadly. The axes are also set to match unity. It seems the issue is not a global axis problem, the transform of each instance gets lost, don't know whether the "issue" is with blender or unity.

Comment: Could you share your model?

Comment: Sure, see edited post, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: thanks for testing, perhaps I wasn't clear with my question but I'm afraid my goal is to be able to create a room made up of the wall instances, THEN export the full room as a finished asset into unity. I need to accomplish this without using joins to keep the possibility of re-editing the walls/rooms in a nice way.

Comment: I understood that way too, there is two possible ways, one is what you did, separated wall, ceiling, window, doors, and so on, so you should export them one by one, by doing this should be easy to create any kind of room. second way is make your room in one mesh and I think yo exported your model in this way that why you have those issues...

Comment: way 1, exporting separate pieces and build a room in unity is what I'm trying to avoid. way 2, I don't see how exporting it as one mesh will be satisfactory since you need to duplicate all pieces and then join them to a room and then export, every time you need to make a change.

Comment: Why you want to avoid way 1? I think that fit best for your case

Comment: As you mention, one way is to compose rooms in unity (or even parts of walls) but the desire is to produce a finished room asset for unity. This may very well be a matter of preference or needs, but before I fall back to an alternative strategy I'd like to investigate how to accomplish this as in the original question. Thank you for taking your time though.